# "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" with ChromiumEdge

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I've seen a lot of iterations of this question, but every single one of them were using Chrome. I'm trying to use Selenium to automate for work, but when I try to run my code on my company computer it fails, even though it was working perfectly on my personal computer. I'm given the error "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: DevToolsActivePort doesn't exist". I think it might be due to the cloud system that my workplace uses, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I attempted fixes suggested to Chrome users, but I haven't been able to pass options to the Edge() initializer.

My code fails already at this point.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Edge()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the argument "--remote-debug-port=xxxx" fixed the issue.

I had some problems with edge-selenium-tools and selenium4, but after uninstalling the former I was able to add options to the Edge driver.